# Where is the definition for object that Get-AzureVm returns?

Tags: powershell, azure

Where do we find the definitions for the objects returned by Powershell commmands like `Get-AzureVm`?

For instance if I do a `Get-AzureVm` I simply get a table with a single row in it with only 3 columns

```
[ServiceName, Name, Status]
```

But code I've 'borrowed' off the net can do so much more:

```
Get-AzureVM | Format-List Name, IpAddress, DNSName, InstanceSize, PowerState
```

I understand the Powershell commands for `Format-List` etc but I don't know where the list of available fields like `IpAddress, DNSName, InstanceSize, PowerState` is defined.

I would have thought the [Get-AzureVm MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt589152.aspx) would tell me but no, nothing.

I also tried the `Azure REST MSDN` [Get information about a virtual machine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163682.aspx) which listed a bunch of properties coming back from a `REST` call, most of which are ignored if i append them to the command above.

They are also missing fields like `IpAddress` so this can't be the definitive/proper list.

So where can I find this info? Seems like such common/basic knowledge that no one has bothered to write it down.

Comment: [`Get-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/8201db21-0fa7-4862-a181-10b89d17d680.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Get-Member` cmdlet to retrieve all available properties:

```
Get-AzureVm | Get-Member -MemberType Property | select Name
```

Output:

```
AvailabilitySetName                                                                                                                                                                
DeploymentName                                                                                                                                                                     
DNSName                                                                                                                                                                            
GuestAgentStatus                                                                                                                                                                   
HostName                                                                                                                                                                           
InstanceErrorCode                                                                                                                                                                  
InstanceFaultDomain                                                                                                                                                                
InstanceName                                                                                                                                                                       
InstanceSize                                                                                                                                                                       
InstanceStateDetails                                                                                                                                                               
InstanceStatus                                                                                                                                                                     
InstanceUpgradeDomain                                                                                                                                                              
IpAddress                                                                                                                                                                          
Label                                                                                                                                                                              
Name                                                                                                                                                                               
NetworkInterfaces                                                                                                                                                                  
OperationDescription                                                                                                                                                               
OperationId                                                                                                                                                                        
OperationStatus                                                                                                                                                                    
PowerState                                                                                                                                                                         
PublicIPAddress                                                                                                                                                                    
PublicIPDomainNameLabel                                                                                                                                                            
PublicIPFqdns                                                                                                                                                                      
PublicIPName                                                                                                                                                                       
ResourceExtensionStatusList                                                                                                                                                        
ServiceName                                                                                                                                                                        
Status                                                                                                                                                                             
VirtualNetworkName                                                                                                                                                                 
VM
```

You can also use `Format-List` to see the properties of your object, try this:

```
Get-AzureVm | Format-List * -Force
```

Comment: That's great thanks. I've watched 20 or so intro videos on powershell and read a bunch of articles and never seen that mentioned. So simple yet so valuable.

Comment: The short version is `fl * -f`. You can for example get detailed information about the last error using `$error[0] | fl * -f`

Comment: All good PS videos should include `Get-Member` and `Format-List *` : )